# WP-CLI: STDOUT error when called in CRON (crontab)

Tags: wp-cli

Little help or guidance. Server is CentOS 7 - with WHM/CPanel installed.

Command:

```
$(which php) $(which wp) core update --require=/opt/wp-cli-pre.php --path=/home/USER/public_html/
```

The contents of /opt/wp-cli-pre.php

```
<?php
if(!defined('STDIN')) define('STDIN',  fopen('php://stdin',  'r'));
if(!defined('STDOUT')) define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
if(!defined('STDERR')) define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));
```

Works as expected from the command line, but if from cron job, I get:

> PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/utils.php on line 1057

output of "which php"
/usr/local/bin/php

output of "which wp"
/usr/local/bin/wp

I have installed the latest WP-CLI from https://wp-cli.org/

Answer (score 1):

At long last, I have found the solution.

When the CRON runs a PHP script like this: */5 * * * * php /path/to/script.php

The SAPI name is: cgi-fcgi (on a WHM/CPanel install on CentOS)

It cannot find the CLI version setup by CPanel at /usr/local/bin/php as the $PATH var is just: /usr/bin:/bin

So, the solution is to not depend on the system environment to determine the PHP you want. But to set that directly.

Like this: */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.php

It was always my assumption that if a CRON was setup in ROOT's crontab, it would inherit ROOT's environment. This apparently is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the following post.

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/users-cannot-use-wp-cli-in-cron.643293/

Comment: Greetings! Many thanks for that. I should have stated that I have searched for and found loads of info. But no solution. The link you posted is a good one. But the solution it presents is to just hide the message. (i.e. use the --quiet param).

Comment: If you haven't tried setting up the cron as per php version then Instead of /usr/bin/php, instead call the interpreter: /opt/cpanel/ea-php##/usr/bin/php-cgi.

The cron would look something like (as an example):
* * * * * /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/example/public_html/exam_wp/cron.php

I hope this helps!

Comment: Getting closer. That causes the same ( undefined constant STDOUT ) error even if I run from the command line. Whereas before it only happened when it was run from cron. So that does help! I will wait for the cron to run and see what happens. Then report back. I suspect that my PHP configuration is not setup correctly for CLI.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. The solution was to use the php-cgi, once I had that and the --require=/opt/wp-cli-pre.php option working, All is well. Many thanks Mohammad!